# How do i use the same factory method for a subclass?

Tags: java, factory

I need a object B, but i get a object A when i execute 'B.GetByID()'

```
public class A 
{
    public A()
    {

    }

    public static A GetSelf()
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public static A GetByID()
    {
        return GetSelf();
    }
}


public class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        super();
    }


    public static B GetSelf()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}


B.GetByID(); //returns A, i need B
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only do that by *also* creating a `B GetByID()` method in `B`. That's somewhat ugly though...

Basically your `B.GetByID()` call will be resolved to `A.GetByID()`; nothing in the compiled code will indicate that it was originally `B.GetByID()`, and the call to `GetSelf()` within `GetByID()` will be resolved to `A.GetSelf()` anyway.

Basically, static methods don't allow for polymorphism in the way you want. I suggest you create an `AFactory` and a `BFactory` subclass, and use method overriding in the normal way, with *instance* methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `GetByID` method to `B`, like so:

```
public class B ... {

    public static B GetByID()
    {
        return GetSelf();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your factory method (no matter in which class it's declared) needs to be aware of both, `A` and `B` and then make a decision on which class to instantiate. If the caller knows it needs a `B`, it just can do a `new B()` anyway, so the factory method has no value there anyway.